# Why won't my discord bot unban correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am working on a general purpose discord bot and I have been struggling with the unban command. I coded this in python. Here is the code:

```
    @client.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
    async def unban(ctx, *, member):
        if member == None:
            await ctx.send("Please enter a username")
            return
        banned_users = await ctx.guild.bans()
        member_name, member_discriminator = member.split("#")
        for ban_entry in banned_users:
            user = ban_entry.user
            if (user.name, user.discriminator) == (member_name, member_discriminator):
                message2 = f"You have been unbanned from {ctx.guild.name}"
                await member.send(message2)
                await ctx.guild.unban(member)
                await ctx.send(f"{member} has been unbanned!")
```

Here is the exception it gives:

```
Ignoring exception in command unban:
Traceback (most recent call last):
          File 
"C:\Users\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\Bot\Bot.py", line 40, in unban
    member_name, member_discriminator = member.split("#")
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

- You are trying to split a string and unpack it into two variables. However, when you splitting the string, the string didn't have any instance of "#" and only returned a list with one string (which is a member). It cannot unpack.
- You should use `commands.MemberConverter` to convert the member argument to a member object immediately. This member object is also what you need to unban. You can't unban a string...
- You don't need to check if `member` is None, since the command will return an error if there was no argument given.
- You shouldn't have to check if the user's name and discriminator are equal, you should use IDs instead.
- As suggested by @justhalf you should put the unban method before sending messages. This is a preventative measure of the unbanning failing, but still sending a message to the member.

When implemented, the code is much shorter and simpler.

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def unban(ctx, member:commands.MemberConverter):
    banned_users = await ctx.guild.bans()
    for ban_entry in banned_users:
        user = ban_entry.user
        if user.id == member.id:
            message2 = f"You have been unbanned from {ctx.guild.name}"
            await ctx.guild.unban(member)
            await member.send(message2)
            await ctx.send(f"{member} has been unbanned!")
```

Comment: Good one. Better if you put `ctx.guild.unban(member)` before `member.send(message2)`

Comment: @justhalf Ah, good catch. Don't want to give false hopes :P

Comment: So I tried this and I feel like I may be missing an import. with the command if user.id == member.id: it seems to be struggling with .id. Am I missing an import? I have import discord and from discord.ext import commands.

Comment: No, no imports are missing. What do you mean it is struggling with `.id`?

Answer (score 0):

```
#unban  
@client.command(aliases=['ub'])
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members = True)
async def unban(ctx, *, member):
    banned_users = await ctx.guild.bans()
    member_name, member_discriminator = member.split("#")

    for ban_entry in banned_users:
        user = ban_entry.user

        if (user.name, user.discriminator) == (member_name, member_discriminator):
            await ctx.guild.unban(user)
            await ctx.send(f'**{user}** has been unbanned!')
            return
```

This unban worked for me, you say [prefix]unban username and discriminator

> unban Bird#7893

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.